# vscode with Node 8 - inspect-brk error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babel-node, vscode-debugger

I've recently upgraded my vscode and now I get this error when I try to run the service:

```
D:\herokuworkspace\server/node_modules/.bin/babel-node.CMD --inspect-brk=27776 src\index.js

D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: bad option: --inspect-brk=27776
```

This is my configuration:

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
```

Please advise what should I change in the configuration in order to make it work again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your title says Node 8, but it looks like you are using an older version of Node that doesn't support the `--inspect-brk` flag. You can upgrade to a version after Node 7.6, or you can set the old debug args in your launch config like this (added port and runtimeArgs):

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
    "runtimeArgs": [ "--inspect=1234", "--debug-brk" ],
    "port": 1234,
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```